# jquery set textfield to current time

Tags: jquery

I was wondering if anyone knew how to set a field in a form to the current time.

I understand that you can use new Date and I was able to use that to capture the date in itself using the following:

```
$('#closuredate').val(new Date().toJSON().slice(0,10));
```

I do not know how to go about the get the time using the above function.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ,,

```
 $( document ).ready(function()
    { 
      new Date($.now());

      var dateObj = new Date();
      var time = dateObj.getHours() + ":" + dateObj.getMinutes() + ":" + dateObj.getSeconds();
      var AMorPM = (dateObj.getHours() >= 12) ? "PM" : "AM";

      $('#closuredate').val(time+AMorPM);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks. This shows me Tue Mar 18 2014 16:41:45 GMT+1100 (AUS Eastern Daylight Time). I would like to only see the time and not the date.

Comment: You are a genius. Thank you. That does work. Quick question though.. if I want to use AM/PM, how would I go about it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this , this works for me

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var dateObj = new Date();
    var time = dateObj.getHours() + ":" + dateObj.getMinutes() + ":" + dateObj.getSeconds();
    $('#closuredate').val(time);
});
```